I can't figure out this android stack trace and how I can fix it, it is affecting many of my users. Does anybody know how to go about this?
    Exception java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked (WindowManagerGlobal.java:544) at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.updateViewLayout (WindowManagerGlobal.java:433) at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.updateViewLayout (WindowManagerImpl.java:155) at android.widget.PopupWindow.update (PopupWindow.java:2226) at android.widget.PopupWindow.update (PopupWindow.java:2347) at android.widget.PopupWindow.alignToAnchor (PopupWindow.java:2517) at android.widget.PopupWindow.-$$Nest$malignToAnchor at android.widget.PopupWindow$1.onViewAttachedToWindow (PopupWindow.java:243) at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow (View.java:21497) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3561) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow (ViewGroup.java:3568) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals (ViewRootImpl.java:3074) at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal (ViewRootImpl.java:2575) at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run (ViewRootImpl.java:9638) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1386) at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run (Choreographer.java:1394) at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks (Choreographer.java:1013) at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame (Choreographer.java:911) at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run (Choreographer.java:1366) at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:942) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:211) at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:300) at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8232) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:580) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1028)
`
I tried to import this to android studio and it doesn't seem to give more insight. Is there a way to know which code in my app is causing this bug?
